# Get the operation record of a payment

Tags: transactions, javascript-sdk, operations, payments

Using the javascript sdk, I'm sending a payment like so:

```
const operation = Operation.payment({
    destination: toAddress,
    asset: asset,
    amount: amount.toString()
});

const account = await server.loadAccount(address);
const transactionBuilder = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account);
transactionBuilder.addOperation(operation);

const transaction = transactionBuilder.build();
transaction.sign(this.keys);

const payment = await this.server.submitTransaction(transaction);
```

This works well, but I also want to get the operation record for that transaction.
It seems that the type of `payment` should be [TransactionRecord](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/stellar-sdk/index.d.ts#L369):

```
interface TransactionRecord extends Record {
    id: string;
    paging_token: string;
    hash: string;
    ledger_attr: number;
    created_at: string;
    max_fee: number;
    fee_paid: number;
    operation_count: number;
    result_code: number;
    result_code_s: string;
    source_account: string;
    source_account_sequence: string;
    envelope_xdr: string;
    result_xdr: string;
    result_meta_xdr: string;
    memo: string;

    account: CallFunction<AccountRecord>;
    effects: CallCollectionFunction<EffectRecord>;
    ledger: CallFunction<LedgerRecord>;
    operations: CallCollectionFunction<OperationRecord>;
    precedes: CallFunction<TransactionRecord>;
    self: CallFunction<TransactionRecord>;
    succeeds: CallFunction<TransactionRecord>;
}
```

But when I try to do this:

```
(await payment.operations())._embedded.records[0] as PaymentOperationRecord;
```

I get an error because `payment.operations` is `undefined`.
I logged the value of `payment` and it was something like:

```
{
    _links: {
        transaction: { 
            href: '...' 
        } 
    },
    hash: '...',
    ledger: 0000000,
    envelope_xdr: '...',
    result_xdr: '...',
    result_meta_xdr: '...' 
}
```

Am I mistaken in thinking that the type of the result should be `TransactionRecord`? And if so, what is this type?  I couldn't find anything in the typescript definition files to match it, and the official documentation doesn't say much about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the object returned from a successful `submitTransaction` call, it is not the transaction record object that you get from calling `server.transactions().transaction(hash)`.

If you would like to get the operation object, you can either decode the `envelope_xdr` or call `server.operations.forTransactions(transactionID)` 
just parse the `transactionID` from the `_links` object of the submitTransaction result. Sample:

```
  server.operations()          
      .forTransaction(transId)
      .call()
      .then(function (opResult) {
          console.log(opResult);              
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
          console.error(err);
      });
```

and you'll get an operation object with this format:

```
{ records:
   [ { _links: [Object],
       id: '44177754433802241',
       paging_token: '44177754433802241',
       source_account: 'GCPRLQQ564KOUEXFEFGODULAT2ME7SCTY5QE6RSGIATZVFQWFVNCDGOR',
       type: 'payment',
       type_i: 1,
       created_at: '2018-07-30T10:16:34Z',
       transaction_hash: 'e52bbe411b14501514420958287c3d0a50554ebff662a26b16a45de6d09fd076',
       asset_type: 'native',
       from: 'GCPRLQQ564KOUEXFEFGODULAT2ME7SCTY5QE6RSGIATZVFQWFVNCDGOR',
       to: 'GATGC7IEHN6SBRPTEGIACCWXB6VHGVA7UYZGOIBE4LFXRSKYCLWO5QH3',
       amount: '2.9900000',
       self: [Function],
       transaction: [Function],
       effects: [Function],
       succeeds: [Function],
       precedes: [Function] } ],
  next: [Function: next],
  prev: [Function: prev] 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to get the operation by issuing a new request (`server.operations().forTransaction(payment.hash).call()`) but I was hoping to avoid that. Does the js-sdk offer any functionality for decoding the `envelope_xdr`?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(StellarSdk.xdr.TransactionEnvelope.fromXDR(transactionResult.envelope_xdr, 'base64'))`

Comment: although you will not get the same transactionrecord object as well.. decoding the envelope_xdr will result to something like this, see the operations object included:
`{"_attributes":{"tx":{"_attributes":{"sourceAccount":{"_switch":{"name":"publicK
eyTypeEd25519","value":0},"_arm":"ed25519","_armType":{"_length":32,"_padding":0
},"_value":{"type":"Buffer","data":[159,21,194,29,247,20,234,18,229,33,76,225,20
9,96,158,152,79,200,83,199,96,79,70,70,64,39,154,150,22,45,90,33]}},"fee":100,"s
eqNum":{"low":48,"high":10125641,"unsigned":true},"memo":{"_switch":{"name":"mem
oText","value":1},"_arm":"

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll stick with the extra `server.operations().forTransaction(payment.hash).call()`

Answer (score 2):

According to the *Stellar* docs and source code, what you get back is just a plain object, straight from Horizon.

https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Server.html#submitTransaction

https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/server.js#L63

Here is more documentation on *what* Horizon returns:

https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/endpoints/transactions-create.md#response

Comment: The kind of TransactionRecord you're mentioning *might* be what gets returned from the transaction *query* endpoint though

Comment: Thanks for the links. The first two are pretty useless though (I have nothing to do with `"Promise that resolves or rejects with response from horizon"`). But the last one is good.